# How do I fix the No Mans Sky token reference error (57127_0xC159B_76561198136931017)?

Tags: technical-issues, no-mans-sky

I'm attempting to play No Mans Sky through Steam on Windows 10 and I'm getting the following error code:

```
57127_0xC159B_76561198136931017
```

My PC is an Asus Q536F with an Nvidia 1050 GTX with Max-Q design, Intel Core i7 8th gen 16 GB of RAM

I have no issues playing anything else except this game. I've tried numerous fixes including reinstalling a lot of programs and more. Has anyone else encountered this issue and know where should I look next?

Comment: Did you verify the integrity of the files through steam? Right click -> Properties -> Local Files -> Verifiy integrity of game files

Comment: Yes, 3 times after switching the game over to integrated graphics card my issue was that I had installed Reshade on Vulkan rendering a while back, and thought i had removed it, apparently I was wrong it screws up Direct 3D 11 rendering in some way on proper graphics cards as to what the specific issue with the card is i do not know.

Comment: Error seems to be a memory failure on instruction. Could you run a memory test?

Comment: As @RandoGamer said, this error comes up at Vulkan issues, +1 for the comment, and even may turn out this to be the valid answer